# Wordpress Docker container not able to connect to DB

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

I am using below codes but my local site is not able to connect to DB

```bash
docker run --name db \
   -p 90:3306 \
   --restart=always \
   --network wp-mysql-network \
   -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root \
   -e MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress \
   -e MYSQL_USER=wpuser \
   -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=P@ssw0rd \
   -v mysql-demo3:/var/lib/mysql \
   -d mysql:latest
```

```bash
docker run --name wp-site1 \
   -d \
   --link db \
   -p 85:80 \
   -e WORDPRESS_HOST=db:90 \
   --network wp-mysql-network \
   -e MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress \
   -e MYSQL_USER=wpuser \
   -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=P@ssw0rd \
   -v wp-data-demo3:/var/www/html \
   wordpress:latest
```

Comment: There's a lot wrong in your commands. You use the wrong variable names and your port number is wrong. Try to find an example online that works and modify it in small steps to suit your needs.

Comment: What error message (if any) do you get?

Answer (score 0):

When you run something like

`docker run -p 90:3306` you expose the internal port 3306 to the machine (machine running docker) port 90.

When you connect a container to another, you should use internal ports so

```sh
docker run -d --name wp-site1 \
    --link db -p 85:80 \
    -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306 \
    --network wp-mysql-network \
    -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress \
    -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wpuser \
    -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=P@ssw0rd \
    -v wp-data-demo3:/var/www/html wordpress:latest
```

Moreover, in your case, you should only expose your frontend, not the backend (database).

If you're successful with wordpress on HTTP, I would suggest to have a look on `Traefik` to handle HTTPS connections.
(an example below).

https://graspingtech.com/wordpress-docker-compose/

### EDIT

1. Create dependencies

   ```sh
   docker network create wp-mysql-network
   docker volume create mysql-demo3
   docker volume create wp-data-demo3
   ```
2. Create database instance

   ```sh
   docker run --name db \
       --network wp-mysql-network \
       -v mysql-demo3:/var/lib/mysql \
       --restart=always \
       -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root \
       -e MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress \
       -e MYSQL_USER=wpuser \
       -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=P@ssw0rd -d mysql:latest
   ```
3. Create the wordpress instance which is connected to db

   ```sh
   docker run -d --name wp-site1 \
       --link db -p 85:80 \
       -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306 \
       --network wp-mysql-network \
       -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress \
       -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wpuser \
       -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=P@ssw0rd \
       -v wp-data-demo3:/var/www/html wordpress:latest
   ```
4. Connect to you wordpress frontend with your web browser

   ```sh
   http://localhost:85
   ```

Comment: Still error remains the same even if i change the port to the internal port 3306 for mysql database

Comment: Please check my edited answer, it should works now.

Comment: same error : Error establishing a database connection

Comment: @vivekchopra91, I've tried multiple times, you could try to refresh `http://localhost:85` it can takes several seconds to be up and running. You may try to remove those containers and starting from scratch. If you struggle to remove `db` : `docker update db --restart=unless-stopped` and then you can stop and remove it.